# Getting the ranking of a photo in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have the following tables:

```
Photos [ PhotoID, CategoryID, ... ] PK [ PhotoID ]
Categories [ CategoryID, ... ] PK [ CategoryID ]
Votes [ PhotoID, UserID, ... ] PK [ PhotoID, UserID ]
```

A photo belongs to one category. A category may contain many photos. A user may vote once on any photo. A photo can be voted for by many users.

I want to select the ranks of a photo (by counting how many votes it has) both overall and within the scope of the category that photo belongs to.

The count of `SELECT * FROM Votes WHERE PhotoID = @PhotoID` being the number of votes a photo has. I want the resulting table to have generated columns for overall rank, and rank within category, so that I may order the results by either.

So for example, the resulting table from the query should look like:

```
PhotoID    VoteCount      RankOverall     RankInCategory
1          48             1               7
3          45             2               5
19         33             3               1
2          17             4               3
7          9              5               5
...
```

...you get the idea. How can I achieve this? So far I've got the following query to retrieve the vote counts, but I need to generate the ranks as well:

```
SELECT     PhotoID, UserID, CategoryID, DateUploaded,
                          (SELECT     COUNT(CommentID) AS Expr1
                            FROM          dbo.Comments
                            WHERE      (PhotoID = dbo.Photos.PhotoID)) AS CommentCount,
                          (SELECT     COUNT(PhotoID) AS Expr1
                            FROM          dbo.PhotoVotes
                            WHERE      (PhotoID = dbo.Photos.PhotoID)) AS VoteCount, Comments
FROM         dbo.Photos
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at something like ([RANK (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) and maybe [DENSE_RANK (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx))

```
SELECT  p.PhotoID,
        ISNULL(v.CountVotes,0) CountVotes,
        RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ISNULL(v.CountVotes,0) DESC) RankInCategory,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY p.CategoryID ORDER BY ISNULL(v.CountVotes,0) DESC) RankInCategory
FROM    Photos p LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  PhotoID,
                    COUNT(PhotoID) CountVotes
            FROM    Votes v 
            GROUP BY    PhotoID
        ) v ON  v.PhotoID = p.PhotoID
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks. I didn't know SQL Server had a function like `RANK()` which ranks equal items the same (as opposed to `ROW_NUMBER()`).